# Como passar informações entre telas, utilizando Bundle e Classes com Get e Set?

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou tentando passar informações de uma tela para outra.

Já tentei de (**2**) **dois** modos:

> - 1) Criei uma class só para criar variáveis e encapsular os métodos
> - 2) Agora, estou tentando passar por bundle sem os métodos encapsulados.
>
> **Problemas 1):** O problema é que **todo** o **get** fica **null** se eu utilizar em outra tela **sem ser** a do **AboutScreen** .
>
> **Problemas 2):** O problema é que está dando o seguinte erro, como se encontra abaixo.

- **ERRO**:

> 06-16 15:28:26.235 16338-16338/com.vuforia.samples.Books
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.vuforia.samples.Books, PID: 16338
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.vuforia.samples.Books/com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Books.Books}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1505)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
>                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                  at com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Books.Books.(Books.java:138)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1072)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2485)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1505) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)

**- AboutScreen.java:**

```
/*===============================================================================
Copyright (c) 2016 PTC Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Qualcomm Connected Experiences, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Vuforia is a trademark of PTC Inc., registered in the United States and other 
countries.
===============================================================================*/

package com.vuforia.samples.Books.ui.ActivityList;

import com.vuforia.samples.Books.R;
import com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Books.Books;
import com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Neoris.Shopping;
import android.Manifest;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class AboutScreen extends FragmentActivity {

    private Button mStartButton;
    private String mClassToLaunch;
    private String mClassToLaunchPackage;

    private TextView txtShoppingName;
    private TextView txtShoppingCity;
    private TextView txtShoppingLat;
    private TextView txtShoppingLong;

    private Location location;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Address endereco;

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String nomeShopping;
    private String licenseKey;
    private String aKey;
    private String sKey;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about_screen);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mClassToLaunchPackage = getPackageName();
        mClassToLaunch = mClassToLaunchPackage + "." + extras.getString("ACTIVITY_TO_LAUNCH");

        /**
         * VERIFICAÇÃO DA PERMISSÃO DO USUÁRIO AO USO DO GPS.
         */

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        } else {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }

        if (location !=null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();

            verificarShopping(latitude, longitude); //Verifica a Lat e Long, retorna o 'Nome do Shopping' e insere as Key's

            try {
                endereco = buscarEndereco(latitude, longitude);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);
        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Cria um Layout para o DialogFragment.
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AboutScreen.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialogo, null);

                Button mComecarButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btn_comecar);

                txtShoppingName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtShoppingName);
                txtShoppingCity = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtShoppingCity);
                txtShoppingLat = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtShoppingLat);
                txtShoppingLong = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtShoppingLong);

                //Insere as Informações ao DialogFragment.
                Shopping shop = new Shopping();

                txtShoppingName.setText(" " + nomeShopping);
                txtShoppingCity.setText(" " + endereco.getLocality());
                txtShoppingLat.setText(" " + latitude);
                txtShoppingLong.setText(" " + longitude);


                //Abre a Activity Books.
                mComecarButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(AboutScreen.this, Books.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

    }

    //Busca em uma List os Endereços da Geolocalização do GPS.
    public Address buscarEndereco(double latitude, double longitude) throws IOException {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        Address address = null;
        List<Address> addresses;

        geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

        if(addresses.size() > 0){
            address = addresses.get(0);
        }

        return address;
    }

    public String verificarShopping(double latitude, double longitude){

        Shopping shop = new Shopping();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Intent intent = new Intent(AboutScreen.this, Books.class);


        if((this.latitude == latitude)&&(this.longitude == longitude)){
            /*FUNCIONA*/shop.setNome("Neoris");
            /*NÃO FUNCIONA EM OUTRA ACTIVITY, SOMENTE NESTA*/shop.setLicenseKey("Ad84Z0z/////AAAAGSgcOhPVvkoniWypHW2Dfsw+iX69sih5qx5JH1PEs92sM2xIhbsKnb2eTNkfBeQymsfgyRswpCDi2Ocu78RH+5+7/fXED7hJPLf3T7k4xKKLl4z8OKfCmr8jE0L5wQdJVV9L3tiHEoUx67M4b3ZSlO3/AzDLYi2/Zt3z8fuPo62osy469O+bKBsKKZtnyX9K7RYwJ2colMQ1bIhQERjg1w5cEZLHUacXAI1ndYhzS2Xl5iwAz98VZ65sptn+PrA5Xno55VGddt7rSBmvwuhZzeyShWnOqiYFhjWg80F3PFv2H/hYfIt4ML37yerJxS/n0z8yFv1H5gPi+Abd5nfaboz/xx1WgXf0yDvQKslFV+rr");

            nomeShopping = shop.getNome();
            licenseKey = shop.getLicenseKey();
            aKey = shop.getAccessKey();
            sKey = shop.getSecretKey();

            // CÓDIGO AQUI
            bundle.putString("aKey", "f854427b00cf89cb4909cf3780a22f1fe6dd1daa");
            bundle.putString("sKey", "16208b50224e2ff8d3c93f069d2c4adf739cea7a");
            intent.putExtras(bundle);

            startActivity(intent);


            return nomeShopping;
        }
        return "oi";
    }



}
```

- **Books.java:**

  package com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Books;

  ```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
  String acKey = bundle.getString("aKey");
  String secKey = bundle.getString("sKey");

  Shopping shop = new Shopping();
  private String kAccessKey = acKey;
  private String kSecretKey = secKey;
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que seu erro diz:

> EXCEPTION: main Process: com.vuforia.samples.Books, PID: 16338
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Sua classe `Books` não está registrado como uma `Activity`

Isto, porque você está chamando ela como uma Activity:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(AboutScreen.this, Books.class);
  startActivity(i);
```

Para registrar como uma Activity (se ela for uma) adicione a seguinte linha no arquivo **AndroidManifest.xml** dentro da TAG `application`:

```
 <activity android:name="com.vuforia.samples.Books"></activity>
```

Segue um exemplo de como passar parâmetros entre as `Activity's`

**Classe onde vamos enviar os dados:**

```
public class ActivityUm extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        Button.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.all)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Vamos chamar a ActivityDois!
                Intent i = new Intent(ActivityUm.this, ActivityDois.class);
//                // Informamos uma chave, para que na próxima tela ele consiga pegar o valor!
                i.putExtra("VALOR_1", "Este é o valor que vamso passar no parametro 1");
                i.putExtra("VALOR_2", 12345L);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Classe onde vamos receber os dados:**

```
public class ActivityDois extends AppCompatActivity{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        //Agora vamos pegar o valor, se o getIntent() não seja nulo!
        if(null != getIntent()){
            /** Pegamos o VALOR_1**/
            final String valor1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("VALOR_1");
            /** Caso seja nulo, o valor será -1**/
            final Long valor2 = getIntent().getLongExtra("VALOR_2", -1L);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: me diga uma coisa. Estou analisando o seu código para testar, porém eu gostaria de saber o seguinte: Em java normal, criamos classes e inserimos as variáveis e seus encapsulamentos. Como faço para utilizar deste modo no Android, utilizando get e set de uma class? Este é o modo correto para utilizar em mobile?